# Is it possible to set CloudWatch alarm for a combination of metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

For example, I want to trigger a CloudWatch alarm for the following:

`Number of messages sent` - `Number of messages deleted` >= 6

The above is for AWS SQS metrics. And I want that metric to trigger AWS Lambda if that alarm is set off.

**Is there any way I can do it? If not, then is there any work-around** [Aiming for a serverless paradigm]

*[I want to do that, cause there's no metric which tells me the number of messages currently (available) in the queue].
So, if there's a metric which can give me that, it'd be very helpful*

Comment: That's a good question, but most of the times, pure metrics are not enough to set alarms and intermediary quantities need to be built and exported to CloudWatch. e.g. maximum of a set of metrics, variation rate of a metric, delta to a goal value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the last overall goal, I would set the alarm on `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` from Cloudwatch [documentation on SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/sqs-metricscollected.html) this is:

> The number of messages available for retrieval from the queue.
>
> Units: Count
>
> Valid Statistics: Average, Minimum, Maximum, Sum, Data Samples
>   (displays as Sample Count in the Amazon SQS console)

---

For the more generic computed metric question I would go with a lambda running priodically, gathering metrics from cloudwatch, doing the maths and pushing back to cloudwatch.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/fbrnc/5739f8bec042ac3326ad) is an example lambda gathering data from Cloudwatch to push to elasticsearch. With the [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html#publishingDataPoints) on the documentation you should be able to push metrics back from the lambda.

Be aware that calling cloudwatch API to gather and push metrics has a cost when you got over 1M request per month, there's other [limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_limits.html) to be aware of to avoid breaking your budget/workflow.

Comment: Thank You (+1). I figured it out a few mins later :D . However, I wasn't sure about the term `Approximate` in it.  Why approximate, when it can tell the *exact* number of messages available?

Comment: Because the metrics are pulled periodically, so they can't guarantee that between the collect time and presentation time there was no change in the queue.

Answer (score 9):

Recently AWS just announced **CloudWatch Metric Math** which should be suitable for your use case.

*References:-*

- [Amazon CloudWatch Adds Metric Math to Enable Custom Operations on Metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/amazon-cloudwatch-adds-metric-math-to-enable-custom-operations-on-metrics/)
- [Create a CloudWatch Alarm Based on a Metric Math Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html)